# Add Layered Navigation to Custom results

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, layered-navigation, manufacturer

I've got a store that is running 1.9.2.4 which was put together by someone else.  It seems they've used a "megabuzz.com" manufacturer plugin to add "brands" as a main navigational element.

Brands are then also added to the layered navigation.  This is fine as we use canonical to only allow layered navigation filters to canonical to the main category.

However, these megabuzz manufacturer pages display a sidebar with a list of brands with the code below in a sidebar.phtml.

```
<?php 
if($brandurl == 'manufacturer'):
$manufacturers = $this->getManufacturers(); 
?>
<?php if (count($manufacturers)): ?>
    <div class="block block-manufacturer">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo Mage::helper('manufacturer')->getConfigTextLabe(); ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <div class="manufacturer-sidebar">
        <ul>
        <?php 
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer): ?>
            <li class="<?php if ($i % 2 == 0): ?>left<?php else: ?>right<?php endif; ?>">
              <a href="<?php echo $this->getManufacturerUrl($manufacturer->getId()); ?>"
                 title="<?php echo $manufacturer->getName(); ?>">
                <?php //echo $manufacturer->getName(); 
                    $arraytitle = explode("-",$manufacturer->getName());
                    //print_r($arraytitle);
                    echo $arraytitle[0];
                ?>
              </a>
            </li>
            <?php $i++; ?>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This isn't very user-friendly and would ideally like to add the layered navigation sidebar filters to the manufacturer pages to replace the above sidebar.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the extension works.

The first thing I would check is whether there is an associated layout XML file in the extension. This can generally be determined by looking at the etc/config.xml file within the extensions app/code directory, which is where any layout files will be registered.

If there is a layout XML file, I would then determine how the change to the sidebar is achieved, usually by searching the file for the template's file name. It could be that commenting out this specific section is all that is required, i.e. it is a directive that is configured to override the default layered navigation, and commenting it out allows the default to be restored.

If not, you may at least have more info to work with.

Another possibility is that that the template itself is being overridden in a layout XML file, overriding block, etc. These are more convoluted approaches, but you never know. In most of these cases, I would search the extension's directories in app/code and app/design for the template file name to determine more about the next steps.

Yet another possibility is that JavaScript is being used to overwrite the sidebar content when the page is loaded by the browser. This seems the least likely but again, you never know.